# CSS: inline and external stylesheet balance?

Tags: css, styles, inline

I am using SEO analyzer, and it tries to make me crazy.
It says that the page has inline css. I have external css, which lists reused styles, but I do not see value to put once-used "style" stuff into this sheet so I leave them in html. I particularly curious about width and height css properties, which I define for images. Why this SEO analyzer does not check for uniqueness of styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in using groups of styles that you only use once is that you may find later on that you may have to use it more than once.  If you already have the appropriate set of rules, it's a simple matter of using the stylesheet selector.  It also makes it easier to update later on since the styles are in a canonical place in the CSS rather than a random place in the html.

As for width/height on `<img>`, these should be done via the *attributes* rather than `style`, and the analyzer should not complain about that -- in fact it should encourage you to use those attributes.

There is probably a lot of subjectivity in the SEO analyzer, but one of the key points of SEO is minimizing download size.  Removing `style` attributes does this.  It does increase the size of the CSS file, though, but probably not by as much.  I'm not sure what effect that has.

Comment: hm... I thought that using style="width:x;height:y" is better way that width="x" height="x". So my assumption is wrong?

Comment: @Eugeny I think that the effect is probably the same, however [these attributes exist specifically for this purpose](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/img#HTML_Attributes)

Comment: My point was that in the past I always used <b>, <i>, width, and other properties and markups. Then it all moved to css. And I assumed that those are going to be deprecated, and I need to move on...

Comment: @Eugeny I don't really understand what changing `<b>`/`<i>` has to do with your question, [but they still exist in HTML](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements) -- you are correct in that you should *always* use CSS for appearance rather than relying on user agent stylesheet changes to elements.

Comment: Thank you. I searched little more and see there's a hot debate on where to put width and height for images - in html, or in css (inline or into external). I am convinced I should use html properties as you pointed me out rather than CSS for sizing images.